# ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath

Tags: java, scala, sbt, log4j

I am creating a simple scala app, and I am using sbt to assemble it and tried to run the jar file I get an error, despite the fact that when I run the script from the ide it works as expected, however, when I try to run it from the jar I get this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger (org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLogger and org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Actually, I am confused how is it running as expected when I run the script in the ide but fails in running the jar? also, I don't call the log4j in any of the code scripts, why is it throwing this error?

I even added these couple of lines to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.19.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.19.0"
```

and did the assembly again, but when I tried to run the jar file again I get the same error, any idea why is this happening and how I can resolve it?

PS: my script uses spark.

Comment: Spark comes with its own versions of libraries and by default will take precedence over yours. You might want to check the JARs after assembly and also the classpath used by Spark.

Comment: thank you for your reply @GaëlJ... how can I do this?